# working with select statement and joins in access 2007

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

guys i am trying to run a select statement in access 2007 and i have problems on how to go about them in access 2007 i want to perform an outer join on two tables but i guess i need some guidance on how to go about it below is my code i tried to run in sql view in access 2007 any ideas i will greatly appreciate

this is my sql statement

```
SELECT  MENU.[C_MENU],  MENU.[C_REC],  AUTO.[C_GROUP]
FROM  MENU
 JOIN  AUTO
ON MENU.[C_MENU]=AUTO.[C_GROUP]
```

first problem is that this sql statement above is giving an error a syntax error and i do not know why its any ideas on how i can correct my error???its flashing on the `Join`

Comment: Try creating your query from Design View instead of SQL View.  Choose the two tables, then click & drag C_MENU from MENU to C_GROUP in AUTO.  That will create a join based on the two fields.  Then right-click on the join line and choose "Join Properties".  In the Join Properties dialog, click the second radio button (*Include ALL records from 'MENU' and only those ...*).  That selection will give you a LEFT JOIN.  Switch from Design View to SQL View to examine the SQL statement the designer created for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [MENU].[C_MENU], [MENU].[C_REC], [AUTO].[C_GROUP]
FROM [MENU]
LEFT JOIN [AUTO] ON [MENU].[C_MENU]=[AUTO].[C_GROUP]
```

Been almost a year since I looked at Access, but I remember it being very finicky about syntax, so you're always better off square-bracketing everything, and including the word "INNER" when you mean "INNER JOIN", instead of using just "JOIN".  But you wanted an "OUTER JOIN", you said?

Comment: sorry I meant left instead of OUTER